# Is US5090167A a valid patent?

Tags: validity, us5090167

Hi I am wondering if this patent- [US5090167A](http://google.com/patents/US5090167) is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

At the very bottom of the page you have linked to at google patents it says it expired in 2000 due to non-payment of maintanance fees.